# python video streaming in tkinter

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I am trying to send a video frame in parts to the server and then build it up again in the client (kind of video streaming) with a UDP socket using threads, tkinter and opencv, but I don't understand my mistake/error, and don't really know if the way I am dividing the video parts is correct.

Server:

```
import socket


IP = "0.0.0.0"
PORT = 8080
LEN = 12000


def main():
    server_socket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    server_socket.bind((IP, PORT))
    while True:
        msg, add = server_socket.recvfrom(LEN)
        server_socket.sendto(msg, add)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Client:

```
import socket
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import cv2
import numpy
import threading


IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 8080
my_socket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
my_socket.connect((IP, PORT))
root = Tk()
main_label = Label(root)
main_label.grid()
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")
LEN = 12000


def send_msg(frame):
    for i in range(0, len(frame), LEN):
        data = frame[i:i+LEN]
        if len(data) == LEN:
            my_socket.sendto(data, (IP, PORT))
        else:
            my_socket.sendto(data + b"done", (IP, PORT))


def recv_msg():
    while True:
        data = b""
        msg, add = my_socket.recvfrom(LEN)
        while b"done" not in msg:
            data += msg
            msg, add = my_socket.recvfrom(LEN)
        data += msg.split(b"done")[0]
        numpy_img = numpy.frombuffer(data, dtype=numpy.uint8)
        numpy_img = numpy_img.reshape((720, 1280, 4))
        img = Image.fromarray(numpy_img)
        tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        main_label.configure(image=tk_img)
        main_label.tk_img = tk_img


def video_stream():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    bytes_img = cv2image.tobytes()
    send_msg(bytes_img)
    main_label.after(50, video_stream)


def main():
    video_stream()
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=recv_msg)
    t1.start()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\eitan\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\eitan\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "E:/Chat/ex_client.py", line 38, in recv_msg
    numpy_img = numpy_img.reshape((720, 1280, 4))
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3182400 into shape (720,1280,4)
```

Would really appreciate help!
thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In the error message, the size matches 1105x720x4  (not 1280x720x4).

Does it work if you set it to that resolution?

```
numpy_img = numpy_img.reshape((720, 1105, 4))
img = Image.fromarray(numpy_img)
```

Also, can you make a test run, which does not forms an image etc., but just prints that the image is received, the size of data etc. and see is that consistent (e.g. the camera actually capturing in that resolution? or it is so because of some default size of the camera window? - I don't know).

```
data = b""
data += msg.split(b"done")[0]
```

That would be inefficient, I think you would better use a numpy array with the expected size and use slicing like you split the frames: [i:i+LEN] etc.

Also, it'd be a good idea to start with hand-shake about the resolution and format (and I guess you realize that, sending it uncompressed as it is an overkill even for LAN).

You may try with different packet sizes (LEN=12000) in order to see whether the error is the same:

```
 LEN=...
 msg, add = my_socket.recvfrom(LEN)
```

Comment: hello! first of all, I really appreciate your help! second of all, sadly, it still prints out the same error but with a different size: " cannot reshape array of size 3216400 into shape (720,1105,4)". If i understood you correctly, by saying "hand-shake", did you mean that i should first send the size of the frame and then start sending the frame in parts?

Comment: Hand-shake - yes, some kind of initial interaction, a protocol. Also you have to check whether that's the correct resolution, the Error messages report that it was not the resolution that you have set.

If you wish 1280x720x4, that's 3686400 bytes, your code doesn't send or receive the right amount of data, either the source image is not 1280x720 (did you check it? cv2.imshow("Frame", frame), and better cv2.imwrite("frame.jpg", frame) - see its resolution) or something in the transmission.

Did you try also the other suggestions?

Comment: Also, you may extend the size of the received data to fit that size 3686400, e.g. create an empty array and copy the received one in the beginning (the rest will be black) and then reshape and see what's the output and post it. Is it with some garbage borders, out of sync etc.
(BTW, if you found an answer/comment useful for your problem, you may mark it.)

Comment: hi! i didn't really understand what you meant. is there a chance you might try to fix the code? if not it's all good!

Comment: Do not try to fit the insufficient data to a fixed resolution, comment that code which creates an image in the receving side and just log/print the size of the received data (print(data.shape) ), print also h, w, c = frame.shape after cv2image = .... and print w * h * c and show the output here - are the values repeating?

Your image is with a wrong resolution.

A way to create an empty image with 4 channels: numpy_img = np.zeros((h, w, 4), h = height, w = width. 

Check also numpy slicing/numpy arrays and basic opencv tutorials with python.

Comment: hi again! data is "bytes" so the shape method does not work, but the length of data is always different. the shape of the video is for sure 720*1280*4. I'm really lost and I keep trying different ways to send the data, but this error keeps appearing

Comment: Shape is for the frame and np arrays. Btw the way they are send is nasty.

Comment: Different - what exact values, please provide as much info as possible for proper help.